# Hide several classes in html table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would need some help. I can only use vanila css, html , javascript

I want to create Buttons that show/hide certain rows in a table I created with with HTML.
If i give every row a class, how can I attach the show/hiding of certain tr to a button?
I tried the other solutions on similar questions but couldnt figure it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

 

 

<body>

    <button onclick="toggleDisplay ('Tim')">Toggle display</button>

   

    

    

    

    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

   

 

  

<table id="myTable">

    <tr>

   

    <th>Group</th>

    <th>Name</th>

    <th>Phone</th>

    </tr>

   

    <tr class="Tim">

        <td>soccer</td>

        <td>name</td>

        <td>Phone number</td>

    </tr>

   

    <tr class="Lea">

        <td>basketball</td>

        <td>name</td>

        <td>9499494</td>

    </tr>

   

       <tr class="3">

        <td>basketball/D</td>

        <td>Eau</td>

        <td>9499545494</td>

    </tr>

   

    

    

       <tr class="3">

        <td>Hockey</td>

        <td>Eau</td>

        <td>9499545494</td>

    </tr>

   

        <tr class="3">

        <td>Hockey</td>

        <td>Eau</td>

        <td>9499545494</td>

    </tr>

   

        <tr class="3">

        <td>marathon</td>

        <td>Eau</td>

        <td>9499545494</td>

    </tr>

   

        <tr class="3">

        <td>sprint</td>

        <td>Eau</td>

        <td>9499545494</td>

    </tr>

   

        <tr class="3">

        <td>sprint</td>

        <td>Eau</td>

        <td>9499545494</td>

    </tr>

   

        <tr class="3">

        <td>sprint</td>

        <td>Eau</td>

        <td>9499545494</td>

    </tr>

   

        <tr class="3">

        <td>cross</td>

        <td>Eau</td>

        <td>9499545494</td>

    </tr>

   

        <tr class="3">

        <td>cross</td>

        <td>Eau</td>

        <td>9499545494</td>

    </tr>

   

        <tr class="3">

        <td>diskus</td>

        <td>Eau</td>

        <td>9499545494</td>

    </tr>

   

        <tr class="3">

        <td>diskus</td>

        <td>Eau</td>

        <td>9499545494</td>

    </tr>

   

        <tr class="3">

        <td>chess</td>

        <td>Eau</td>

        <td>9499545494</td>

    </tr>

   

        <tr class="3">

        <td>chess</td>

        <td>Eau</td>

        <td>9499545494</td>

    </tr>

   

    

    

</table>   

 

 

<script>

 

 

    function toggleDisplay(target) {

        let matches = document.querySelectorAll("." + target);

        matches.forEach(function (match) {

            if (match.style.display == "none")

                match.style.display = "block";

            else

                match.style.display = "none";

        });

    }

   

  function myFunction() {

  // Declare variables

  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;

  input = document.getElementById("myInput");

  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

  table = document.getElementById("myTable");

  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

 

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {

    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

    if (td) {

      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;

      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {

        tr[i].style.display = "";

      } else {

        tr[i].style.display = "none";

      }

    }

  }

}

 

</script>

   

    

</body>
```

Best Wishes
Tylah

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve], SO isn't a free code service, so we expect you have try something, so pleas post your code in your question

Comment: Will do in the future.
My bad for not posting what I tried :)

Comment: Tylah: you can edit your post and add the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function that takes in the target class name. With the class name you can query the document for all nodes that match, and change the `node.style.display` attribute.

```
function toggleDisplay(target) {
        let matches = document.querySelectorAll("." + target);
        matches.forEach(function (match) {
            if (match.style.display == "none")
                match.style.display = "block";
            else
                match.style.display = "none";
        });
    }
```

To call this function from a button press, simply add it to the onclick attribute of the button.

```
<button onclick="toggleDisplay('className')">Toggle display</button>
```

Update: This version handles arrays of class names instead.

```
function toggleDisplay(targets) {
    targets.forEach(function (target) {
        let matches = document.querySelectorAll("." + target);
        matches.forEach(function (match) {
            if (match.style.display == "none")
                match.style.display = "block";
            else
                match.style.display = "none";
             });
    });
}
```

Button needs and update aswell.

```
<button onclick="toggleDisplay(['ClassName1', 'ClassName2', 'ClassName3'])">Toggle display</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much R.A.E.
So if my <tr class="1">  i have to set...
function toggleDisplay(1) {
        let matches = document.querySelectorAll("." + 1);
        matches.forEach(function (match) {
            if (match.style.display == "none")
                match.style.display = "block";
            else
                match.style.display = "none";
        });
    }
<button onclick="toggleDisplay('1')">Toggle display</button> ?

Comment: You don't need to modify the function at all. All you need to do is add the button and change the `className` to whatever class you give your table row

Comment: Hey R.A.E at the moment Iam trying to hide multiple classes at the same time. 
If I use ['ClassName1', ' ClassName2' ] in the onclick line the process stops working. 
If you could give me a hint where I can find information regarding that issue it would be great :)
I thought about using an array in java to safe the classes i want to hide and than hide those with the onclick target button

Comment: Hello @Tylah1998 What's stopping you from giving multiple elements the same class? Let's say you have 3 elements that you want to hide, you could give them the same class `hideTarget1` and then have the button call `toggleDisplay('hideTarget1')`. This will hide all 3 elements. You could then expand this to have more buttons that target different classes :) If you want the toggleDisplay function to take in an array of class names, that can be done aswell.

Comment: Hey R.A:E thank you for your response.  I added the Code now:)
The first option doesn't work since I have to mix the classes that are assigned to the button.
I have for example button 1. which says Chess--> and that should  display all rows of persons  that are in the group of chess and hide all other groups.
And do that for all Groups and Persons. I have several Persons in each group as well, and each button should show the specific group and hide all other.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example of how to handle an array of classnames instead.

Comment: Thank you R.A.E 
Can't thank you enough.
Is there any way to contribute or support ?

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :) Keep on improving your skills and come back to StackOverflow to help others in need!